# Simple Injector: Replace registered type at runtime

Tags: c#, simple-injector

Is there any way in Simple Injector to replace the default of one type at runtime as `containter.Inject()` in Structure Map? I borrow the [code](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/changing-configuration-at-runtime/) using Structure Map as follows

```
var container = new Container(x => { x.For<IFoo>().Use<AFoo>(); });
container.GetInstance<IFoo>().ShouldBeOfType<AFoo>();
container.Configure(x => x.For<IFoo>().Use<BFoo>());

// The default of IFoo is now different
container.GetInstance<IFoo>().ShouldBeOfType<BFoo>();

// or use the Inject method that's just syntactical
// sugar for replacing the default of one type at a time
container.Inject<IFoo>(new CFoo());

container.GetInstance<IFoo>().ShouldBeOfType<CFoo>();
```

My context

Register container

```
// bypass verify was removed for short
_container.Register<HttpContextBase>(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)); 
_container.Register(() => _container.GetInstance<HttpContextBase>().User.Identity);
```

My service

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public MyService(IIdentity identity)
    {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

There is no problem with my app. It worked. But in my unit tests (real local DB without mock), I want to replace IIdentity with logged in user. I used Structure Map and it worked. Now I do not how to make it works with Simple Injector.

Comment: Why do you want to replace an instance at runtime?

Comment: OP I presume you've also read the paragraph below the code snippet? "First off, the best advice on this functionality is *don't use it outside of testing scenarios on the root container*."

Comment: @Steven I updated my question with current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But in my unit tests (real local DB without mock), I want to replace IIdentity with logged in user.

You can absolutely replace the real `IIdentity` registration with a different one for unit testing. You simply have to do this *before* resolving from the container.

This means that *every* integration test (I say 'integration', since a unit test should *not* use a DI Container) should get its own `Container` instance. Secondly, to be able to override existing registrations, you will have to set `container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations`. For more information, read [this](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#override-existing-registrations).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's actually integration tests. I thought about this solution before asking the question. I just want to find another cleaner solution without touching veryfing container.